# Record selectors in Haskell's Type Classes

Tags: haskell, types, record, typeclass

I want to implement a `Type Class` with few default methods, but I'm getting an error, that I cannot use `record selectors` inside `type classes` definitions.

The following code basically creates `type class` which defines `add` function, which should add an element to the `repr` record of some `data type`. Here is the code:

```
import qualified Data.Graph.Inductive     as DG

class Graph gr a b where
    empty :: DG.Gr a b
    empty = DG.empty

    repr :: gr -> DG.Gr a b

    -- following function declaration does NOT work:
    add :: a -> gr -> gr
    add el g = g{repr = DG.insNode el $ repr g}
```

The compiler throws error:

```
repr is not a record selector
In the expression: g {repr = DG.insNode el $ repr g}
In an equation for add:
    add el g = g {repr = DG.insNode el $ repr g}
```

Is it possible to declare such methods in Haskell?

**Clarification**

I need such design because I've got some `data types`, which behave in simmilar way. Lets say, we got `A`, `B` and `C` `data types`. Each of them should have a record `repr :: DG.Gr a b`, where `a` and `b` are distinct for each of `A`, `B` and `C`.

`A`, `B` and `C` share the same functions, like `add` or `delete` (which basically add or delete elements to record `repr`). If these data types share a lot of functions it make sense to implement the functions in `type class` and make instances of this `type class` - these functions will be implemented for each of our `data type` automatically.

Additional I would love some of these `data types` (lets say I want `B`) to behave slighty different when calling `add` function on it. It is easy to implement this behaviour when making `instance` of the `type class` for `B`.

Comment: The answer is "no", but "sort of, using lenses", but more importantly I feel there is a fundamental misunderstanding of what classes are for somewhere here. It would help a lot if you said _why_ you want to have such a class; we may be able to suggest a more idiomatic alternative.

Comment: @DanielWagner - I've added a clarification for the problem I'm trying to solve - I hope it is enought clear now, why I'm trying to do this :)

Comment: See my updated answer. In second example I use `update` method which perform the actual update (can be implemented using that record update syntax in instances), and third example uses `Control.Lens`.

Comment: @JJJ I think lenses are what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The record update syntax

   ```
    <record-instance> { <record-field-name> = ..., ... }
   ```

   works when `<record-instance>` is an instance/term of a *known* algebraic data type (so that `<record-field-name>` is it known field), in your code it is just some (ad-hoc) polymorphic parameter `gr`, so you need first to convert `gr` to `Gr`, then update it, and then...
2. I think that `gr` and `Gr` should be equivalent in some sense, i.e. we need an inverse function for `repr`, say `iface`, to be able to implement `add`.

Here is an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

data Gr a b = Gr { _internal :: [(a, b)] } deriving ( Show, Read )

class Graph gr a b where

  repr :: gr -> Gr a b
  iface :: Gr a b -> gr

  -- iface . repr == id {gr}
  -- repr . iface == id {Gr a b}

  -- add element via "interface" (get a representation via @repr@, update it, and then 
  -- return an interface back with @iface@)
  add :: (a, b) -> gr -> gr
  add el g = let r = repr g in iface r { _internal = el : _internal r }
  -- or
  add el = iface . insNode el . repr where
    insNode x (Gr xs) = Gr (x : xs) -- or whatever

instance Graph String Int Int where
  repr = read
  iface = show

test :: String
test = add (1 :: Int, 2 :: Int) "Gr { _internal = [] }"
-- test => "Gr {_internal = [(1,2)]}"
```

---

If some data types `A` and `B` *aggregate* `Gr a b` (so that we can't write an inverse for `repr`), then we can do something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

data Gr a b = Gr [(a, b)] deriving ( Show )

class Graph gr a b where

  repr :: gr -> Gr a b

  update :: gr -> (Gr a b -> Gr a b) -> gr
  -- 2: update :: gr -> Gr a b -> gr

  add :: (a, b) -> gr -> gr
  add el g = update g $ insNode el
    -- 2: update g (insNode el $ repr g)
    where insNode x (Gr xs) = Gr (x : xs)

data A = A { _aRepr :: Gr Char Char, _aRest :: Char } deriving ( Show )
data B = B { _bRepr :: Gr Int Int, _bRest :: Int } deriving ( Show )

instance Graph A Char Char where
  repr = _aRepr
  update r f = r { _aRepr = f $ _aRepr r }
  -- 2: update r g = r { _aRepr = g }

instance Graph B Int Int where
  repr = _bRepr
  update r f = r { _bRepr = f $ _bRepr r }
  -- 2: update r g = r { _bRepr = g }

testA :: A
testA = add ('1', '2') $ A (Gr []) '0'
-- => A {_aRepr = Gr [('1','2')], _aRest = '0'}

testB :: B
testB = add (1 :: Int, 2 :: Int) $ B (Gr []) 0
-- => B {_bRepr = Gr [(1,2)], _bRest = 0}
```

---

It is also possible to use [lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data Gr a b = Gr [(a, b)] deriving ( Show )

insNode :: (a, b) -> Gr a b -> Gr a b
insNode x (Gr xs) = Gr (x : xs)

class Graph gr a b where
  reprLens :: Simple Lens gr (Gr a b)

add :: Graph gr a b => (a, b) -> gr -> gr
add el = reprLens %~ insNode el

data A = A { _aRepr :: Gr Char Char, _aRest :: Char } deriving ( Show )
data B = B { _bRepr :: Gr Int Int, _bRest :: Int } deriving ( Show )

makeLenses ''A
makeLenses ''B

instance Graph A Char Char where
  reprLens = aRepr

instance Graph B Int Int where
  reprLens = bRepr

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let a = A (Gr []) '0'
      b = B (Gr []) 0
  print $ add ('0', '1') a
  print $ add (0 :: Int, 1 :: Int) b
-- A {_aRepr = Gr [('0','1')], _aRest = '0'}
-- B {_bRepr = Gr [(0,1)], _bRest = 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (which uses tuple list as example instead of `DG`)

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, TypeSynonymInstances #-}

class MyClass g a b | g -> a b where
      extract :: g -> [(a,b)]
      construct :: [(a,b)] -> g 

      empty :: g
      empty = construct []

      add :: (a,b) -> g  -> g
      add i d = construct $  [i] ++ (extract d) 

data A  = A {reprA :: [(Int,Int)]}

instance MyClass A Int Int  where
         extract = reprA
         construct = A

data B  = B {reprB :: [(String,String)]}

instance MyClass B String String  where
         extract = reprB
         construct = B
```