# Invalid record selector and type classes

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a class `Movable` and multiple data types that instance this class. I want to create a generic move function for all these classes as I did below, but apparently my record syntax is incorrect since I get the following error:

```
src\Controller.hs:24:13: error:
    * `position' is not a record selector
    * In the expression: o {position = (x', y')}
      In an equation for `move':
          move o
            = o {position = (x', y')}
            where
                (x, y) = position o
                (vx, vy) = velocity o
                x' = x + vx
                y' = y + vy
   |
24 | move o = o {position = (x', y')}
   |             ^^^^^^^^
```

I tried applying this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763438/record-selectors-in-haskells-type-classes), but I didn't get it to work. **How to fix this? Or are there other ways beside using record syntax to solve this problem?**
Here you can see my code:

```
type Position = (Float, Float)
type Velocity = (Float, Float)

class Movable m where
    position :: m -> Position
    velocity :: m -> Velocity

data Player = Player { 
                playerBulletType :: Bullet,
                playerHealth :: Health,
                playerMaxVelocity :: MaxVelocity,
                playerVelocity :: Velocity,
                playerPosition :: Position,
                playerSprite :: Sprite
              }

instance Movable Player where
    position = playerPosition
    velocity = playerVelocity

move :: Movable o => o -> o
move o = o {position = (x', y')}
  where (x, y) = position o
        (vx, vy) = velocity o
        x' = x + vx
        y' = y + vy
```

Comment: Well you did not define a record type with a field `position`, so this is expected behavior. You here define `position` as some sort of "getter", so even if somehow you can call a "setter" like this, it would not make much sense.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  don't understand, I said I defined classes that have a Movable instance (as you can now see in the question's code).

Comment: A `class` in Haskell is more what is an "interface" in other programming languages. You here define functions like: `position :: m -> Position`, so it "converts" a `Movable` to a `Position`, not the other way around.

Comment: But doesn't this question look like the one I linked to? @willemVanOnsem

Comment: but here you only assign fields defined in the `data` clause.

Comment: @willemvanonsem so there is no way in haskell to get this kind of behavior? A function that works on multiple data types that all have the Movable class?

Comment: you can define a "setter" like `setPosition -> Position -> m -> m` and then call the "setter".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as [we already recommended in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896071/haskell-inheritance-data-constructors/52896589#52896589), you should probably not use *any class at all* for this problem, but just a parameterised record.

A class is not like in OO that it actually defines a data structure. It just defines some operations that may use *values of the instance type* to give you something, but that's just a special case. Those values might as well be computed on the fly, and there's generally no way to *set* them to another value. If you need that, then such a “getter method” is not sufficient, you also need a “setter”. Idiomatically in modern Haskell, you'd do both in one go: the combination of getter an setter is called a [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens.html).

```
import Control.Lens

class Movable m where
  position :: Lens' m Position
  velocity :: Lens' m Velocity

instance Movable Player where
  position f plyr = fmap (\p -> plyr{playerPosition=p}) . f $ playerPosition plyr
  velocity f plyr = fmap (\v -> plyr{playerVelocity=v}) . f $ playerVelocity plyr
```

Then you can write

```
move :: Movable o => o -> o
move o = o & position .~ (x', y')
  where (x, y) = o ^. position
        (vx, vy) = o ^. velocity
        x' = x + vx
        y' = y + vy
```

or, shorter with [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space),

```
import Data.AffineSpace

move :: Movable o => o -> o
move o = o & position %~ (.+^ o^.velocity)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. As you've now twice suggested, I'll use the parameterised way. I only wanted to also know how to use this approach.